# Read all JSON files in directory and append them to a CSV in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

Thanks in advance for your willingness to assist.  I've got a bunch of JSON files in a directory.  The names are never really known.

I'm looking for assistance to:
(1) Read all the JSON files
(2) Append the data in the JSON files to output.csv
(3) Once a JSON files data has been appended, add "-Appended" to end of filename

Comment: JSON is hierarchical, csv is table... This task can not be solved in common case. Need more information about your data.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You need to do some work. Try something, and if you get stuck somewhere, ask a specific question about what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read all of the json files you will need to know the file names.  To do this use [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).  From there you can [read each file individually](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) into a buffer using array.ForEach().  This can be manipulated into a csv format by enumerating through the buffer elements and adding commas.  Finally, rename the file using fs.rename.
Hope this helps.